# PageSetupDialog - saving and loading custom Page Size issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this strange issue with PageSetupDialog. After user select "Page Size" (A4,A5,B5,etc..) from the combobox i save the PaperSize.RawKind for later use so when user returns to PageSetupDialog it will remember previous user selected "Page Size".

If user selected a "Page Size" which is not in the enum of PageKind (aka custom kind, Like 'B5 (ISO)' ), that "Page Size" will not automatically selected again in combobox after user returns to "Page Setup" dialog, but will just show default Paper Size: "Letter". Only PageKind Enum  automatically get selected in combobox of "Paper Size".

To select a Paper Size i can just do:

```
int MyLastPaperSize=5;
dlg.PageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind= MyLastPaperSize;
```

[image]

This is the enum list: : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize.rawkind(v=vs.110).aspx

Using framework 4.0 and C#. any help is appreciated. tried many ways and couldn't make this work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting only `PaperSize.RawKind` indeed doesn't restore previous (or initial) "Size".

Saving complete `PageSettings` will restore everything, including "Size":

```
PageSettings _settings = new PageSettings();

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new PageSetupDialog();
    dialog.PageSettings = _settings;
    dialog.ShowDialog();
    _settings = dialog.PageSettings;
}
```

Clicking button again will restore settings from previously shown dialog.

I had a strange issue when this didn't work at first, changing other properties (e.g. margins) temporarily seems to fix it for me. Can't reproduce it anymore, but may be worth to note.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Didn't try it out yet, because i need a way to save the PageSettings . Currently i just save PaperSize, Orientation and margins parameters separately into Resources.rsx  file.

Comment: Anyhow, i tried it with saving the whole printdocument (that includes PageSettings) and sending it back and still it gives me the same result. Doesn't work with custom kind "Paper Size"., always shows me "Letter" in combo box.

Comment: Note that  it only happens with Paper Size  Kind (PaperSize.Kind) set to "custom". If you can please recheck if the "Paper Size" property is restored when selecting  a PaperSize that it's PaperSize.Kind='custom'

Comment: I don't have "custom", but it seems to work with any option available to me, e.g.: A6, Envelope Monarch, Folio, Officio II (8.5 x 13 inch), ...

Comment: Thanks for the tests, it seems they are all a part of:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize.rawkind(v=vs.110).aspx (aka non custom type) as you said. The issue can only be reproduced with 'custom' Kind, otherwise it works also for me. Actually the only way i can see to solve this to build my own custom PageSetupDialog :\